# Darksky skycons dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, sharepoint

Is there a way to dynamically set the icon with the skycons?

http://darkskyapp.github.io/skycons/

```
let test = "CLEAR_DAY";
skycons.add("icon1", Skycons.test); //This is not working, getting "test" from api

skycons.add("icon1", Skycons.CLEAR_DAY); //This works
```

Is there a way to do this without using a if statement for every icon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove "Skycons." and it works.

```
skycons.add("icon1", test);
```